# IOS Drawing image on image memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, uiimage, core-graphics, retina-display, drawimage

I'm trying to draw text in a UIImageView with the method below.
Problem is that that method is called from inside a loop that iterates 32 times (in this specific case). I dies right after the "text image ready" on the 14th call.

Unfortunately when I look for leaks using instruments the app dies before I can get anything.
I'm not quite sure what should I be releasing or if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!

```
-(void) writeNameToImage:(int)soundIndex setNumber:(int)setNumber
{

    NSString* strTextToWrite;

    if(setNumber==1)
        strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects1 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;
    else 
        strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects2 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;

    NSLog(@"string to draw: %@",strTextToWrite);
    //Retrieve image from UIImageView
    UIImage* layerToUpdate= imgViewRecorded.image;


    //***** Drawing the text image.
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    CGSize size  = [strTextToWrite sizeWithFont:font];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);


    // draw in context, you can use also drawInRect:withFont:
    [[UIColor whiteColor] set];
    [strTextToWrite drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0) withFont:font];

    // transfer image
    UIImage* imgToAdd = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSLog(@"text image ready");
    //**** Finished drawing text image

    //**** Updating layer image with generated image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layerToUpdate.size, FALSE, 0.0);
    NSLog(@"layer created in context");
    [layerToUpdate drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, layerToUpdate.size.width, layerToUpdate.size.height)];

    //translate to the center
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.width, 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;
    //rotate with the center of the image as the rotation point
    CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( degrees ) );
    //translate back to original position
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.width, -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;

    if(setNumber==1)
        [imgToAdd drawInRect:CGRectMake( (303-(imgToAdd.size.width/2)), 80, imgToAdd.size.width, imgToAdd.size.height)];
    else
        [imgToAdd drawInRect:CGRectMake( (303-(imgToAdd.size.width/2)), 23, imgToAdd.size.width, imgToAdd.size.height)];

    NSLog(@"text drawn to layer");

    CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( degrees ) );
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //[layerToUpdate release];
    NSLog(@"assigning new created image");
    imgViewRecorded.image = newImage;

}
```

I noticed that if I add `[newImage release]` at the end of the method it runs completely but clearly leads to a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

***Update***

I have tried this other solution but in this case the text gets gradually blurry. Meaning that the first text I drew is the bluriest and the last one looks perfectly clear. I think this can be due to the retina scale but I dont know how to fix that.

```
-(void) writeSoundNameToImage:(int)soundIndex setNumber:(int)setNumber
{

    NSString* strTextToWrite;

    if(setNumber==1)
        strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects1 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;
    else 
        strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects2 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;


    NSLog(@"string to draw: %@",strTextToWrite);


    //***** Drawing the text image.
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    CGSize size  = [strTextToWrite sizeWithFont:font];



    UIImage* layerToUpdate= imgViewRecorded.image;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate( NULL,layerToUpdate.size.width,layerToUpdate.size.height, 8, 4  * layerToUpdate.size.width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);


    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, layerToUpdate.size.width, layerToUpdate.size.height), layerToUpdate.CGImage);


    //translate to the center
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.width, 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;
    //rotate with the center of the image as the rotation point
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( ((soundIndex-1)*self.myProfile.degreesPerSound)+self.myProfile.degreesPerSound/2 ) );
    //translate back to original position
    CGContextTranslateCTM( context, -0.5f*layerToUpdate.size.width, -0.5f*layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;

    char* text = (char *)[strTextToWrite cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    CGContextSelectFont(context, "Helvetica", 15, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFillStroke);

    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1);

    if(setNumber==1)
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, (303-(size.width/2)), 600-90, text, strlen(text));
    else
        CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, (303-(size.width/2)), 600-33, text, strlen(text));

    CGContextRotateCTM(context, -CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS( ((soundIndex-1)*self.myProfile.degreesPerSound)+self.myProfile.degreesPerSound/2 ) );

    //CGContextScaleCTM(context, layerToUpdate.size.width/scale, layerToUpdate.size.height/scale);

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    UIImage* newImage=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

    imgViewRecorded.image =newImage;



    CGImageRelease(imageMasked);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

}

Comment: This code doesn't happen to be on a thread is it?

Comment: you are correct, is not. Should I use performSelectorInBackground or performSelectorOnMain??

Comment: I just ask because graphics contexts can only begin and end on main, because they are not thread safe.  Additionally, it does not appear that your problem is a memory leak, but rather a runtime error, otherwise it wouldn't just die.

But the whole invocation in a @try/catch block and ask for a description of the exception, it may help shed some light on what is happening.

Comment: I just added the try/catch and unfortunately it never goes inside the catch...
When I've had leaks in the past this was the same behaviour. The app just exits. I guess it depends on how big the leak is.

Comment: Did you compile with debug symbols on?

Comment: by the way if i run using the IOS Simulator it works properly.

Comment: Definitely not an exception. I used the "Add Exception Breakpoint" for all exceptions. And it just died without stoping at any point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case since this was for the image initialization I ended up doing the following.

```
UIImage* layerToUpdate= imgViewRecorded.image;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layerToUpdate.size, FALSE, 0.0);


NSLog(@"layer created in context");
[layerToUpdate drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, layerToUpdate.size.width, layerToUpdate.size.height)];
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];

for (int i=0; i<self.myProfile.totalSounds; i++)
{ 
    //translate to the center
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.width, 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;
    //rotate with the center of the image as the rotation point
    CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), degrees );
    //translate back to original position
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.width, -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;

    NSString* strTextToWrite;

    //do set one first
    strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects1 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;
    CGSize size  = [strTextToWrite sizeWithFont:font];

    [strTextToWrite drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((303-(size.width/2)), 80.0) withFont:font];

    //do set 2
    strTextToWrite= ((MyObject*)[arrObjects2 objectAtIndex:soundIndex-1]).soundName;
    size  = [strTextToWrite sizeWithFont:font];

    [strTextToWrite drawAtPoint:CGPointMake((303-(size.width/2)), 23.0) withFont:font];

    //translate to the center
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.width, 0.5f * layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;
    //rotate back
    CGContextRotateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -degrees );
    //translate back to original position
    CGContextTranslateCTM( UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.width, -0.5f *layerToUpdate.size.height ) ;
}

UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

imgViewRecorded.image =  newImage;
```

The difference between the two is quite clear I was creating several number of contexts in the past without knowing when their resources were going to be released causing the memory leak and the app to exit. In the later one I create a unique context and manipulate it to draw all the text I need to draw.

Hope this come handy to someone.

Comment: I just stumbled across the identical issue last night, implementing a similar solution. In my case, I created an extension to UIImage to add text to an image. When it ran in a loop, it blew memory. I'll modify the code to manage the context outside of the loop. Thanks for identifing the issue.